# QGLWidget context destruction

Tags: c++, qt, opengl, qobject, qglwidget

I have a class named `Mesh` which wraps and OpenGL object, with VBO, texture, etc. This class inherits from `QObject` and its parent is set to my `QGLWidget`. So as soon I close the widget it will get deleted by QObject system.

But I have a problem because this mesh class has a destructor that does some OpenGL calls to cleanup. When QObject child destructor kicks in, the OpenGL context is already destroyed and I get a segfault.

How I can make sure that my `~Mesh()` destructor will get called before `QGLWidget` context gets deleted?

Comment: I'd suggest checking out QOpenGLContext and managing it yourself.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could delete the `Mesh` object explicitly in the destructor of your `QGLWidget` derived class, because everything you put in there would be executed before `~QGLWidget()` itself (and before `~QObject()` which is responsible for the deletion of child objects).

Or you can make the object a non-pointer member, or wrap it in a smart pointer to achieve the same result.